# IBM DB2 split functionality

Tags: sql, db2

Is there a way to use **SPLIT** in DB2?

I have a table name `sales` where we are saving years and products information in comma-separated VARCHAR. I'm trying to split the values by comma to perform another SQL query but I can't find a good way to split the text like String_Split in SQL Server. Can anyone help me with that?

**Please note: Products and Year columns are very long text**

Table: SALES
[image: Sales Table Data]

Comment: Which OS? There is a SPLIT function in iSeries. For LUW check out the tokenize function https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc/doc/xqrfntkz.html for Db2 z/OS XML functionality can be used (XMLPARSE)

Comment: This would be a great opportunity to reorganize this table into multiple rows, one product/year tuple per row

Comment: Please, add to your question the result desired on this sample input data.

Comment: What results do you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte_p(id, rest, product, lev) as (
      select id, products || ',' as rest, '' as product, 0 as lev
      from t
      union all
      select id, substring(rest, instr(rest, ',') + 1), left(rest, instr(rest, ',') - 1), lev + 1
      from cte_p
      where rest <> ''
     ),
     cte_y(id, rest, year, lev) as (
      select id, years || ',' as rest, '' as years, 0 as lev
      from t
      union all
      select id, substring(rest, instr(rest, ',') + 1), left(rest, instr(rest, ',') - 1), lev + 1
      from cte_y
      where rest <> '' 
     )
select p.id, p.product, y.year
from cte_p p join
     cte_y y
     on p.id = y.id
where p.lev > 0 and y.lev > 0;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=0308979f5846eecff47fc5f6906f9338) is a db<>fiddle.